# Can't make a panel animation work through clicking on UI button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a "Try Again" button work with a panel animation that's supposed to go from transparent to thick black before loading the game scene again. But for some reason the animation is not running nor the load scene line.I'm finding it odd.

At first I thought the panel was blocking me from clicking the button, so I set it inactive as default, and activate it through script.
I think I've set the references correctly, one for the panel animator, one for the panel itself (to set it active), one for "OnClick" section of the tryagain button and assigning the correct function from it in the inspector.

```
public class Tryagainscript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator tryagain;
    public AudioSource audios;
    public AudioClip tsu;
    public GameObject panel;

    IEnumerator TryCo()
    {

        tryagain.SetInteger("try", 1);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.2f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }

    public void Trybutton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PanelCo());
    }

    IEnumerator PanelCo()
    {
        panel.SetActive(true);
        audios.PlayOneShot(tsu);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        StartCoroutine(TryCo());
    }
}
```

The names of the variables might be confusing, but you get the idea.
This is the script I assign to the TryAgain button to run the "Trybutton()" function so it runs both coroutines, one at a time. The integer "try" referes to the animator in the panel to go pitch black.
As I said though, nothing is working from this code: the panel is not going pitch black nor the game is loading back.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I've changed the code to something simpler:

```
  public void Trybutton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PanelCo());
    }

    IEnumerator PanelCo()
    {

        audios.PlayOneShot(tsu);
        panel.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.2f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");

    }
```

Instead of changing animation states, I set the desired one as default and just set the panel active.
The wierd part is (because I don't have the knowledge to understand it), the TryAgain button belongs to a GameOver menu panel. When the game starts with this GameOver panel active (but not the fading to black one), the script runs just fine. On the other hand, when I play and lose on purpose, the game over menu pops up, I press the TryAgain button and all it does is play the sound reffered by "tsu" before "waitforseconds()". No panel, no scene restart, although in the Inspector the panel shows as Active and full black.
Thanks again for your responses!

Comment: Are you sure the button calls trybutton?

Comment: Can you set breakpoints and debug your code to see if all lines are called in the correct order?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes. I've changed the script a little to simplify it, but it's still now working.
```
  public void Trybutton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PanelCo());
    }

    IEnumerator PanelCo()
    {
        
        audios.PlayOneShot(tsu);
        panel.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.2f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
        
    }
```
The weirdest thing is: The TryAgain button belongs to the "GameOver" menu panel, and when the game starts with this menu active, the script runs just fine.

Comment: Where is your `Tryagainscript` attached to; Is the gameobject/component of it active when you invoke `Trybutton()`?

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit, as it was inappropriate for this site. It is not acceptable to add SOLVED (in any form) to the title or to edit the solution into the question itself. If you want to share the solution you found, the proper way to do so is by posting an answer in the space below provided for that purpose; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I'm relatively new to the site. 
I'm glad you explained!

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm feeling kind of dumb right now. I figured that the panel animation wasn't running after the player died so I investigated around it. I remembered then that I'd set the timeScale to 0f when the player dies. That's why the fading panel was not animating and the scene was not restarting. 
I did not think about this before because I did not know the scene could not load if the timeScale was set to 0f.
Thank you again for your time, attention and answers guys! 
I'm a newbie at this still.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way to use couroutines in Unity (Fade out example):

```
IEnumerator Fade() 
{
    for (float ft = 1f; ft >= 0; ft -= 0.1f) 
    {
        Color c = renderer.material.color;
        c.a = ft;
        renderer.material.color = c;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
    }
}
```

Don't try to reinvent the wheel this is the standard way to do a Fade Out (I think you want a Fade In). Here its changing the alpha value (c.a) decreasing it 0.1 each 0.1 seconds.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: What? This is surely not a "standard" way of using Coroutines ... Why not using `ft -= 0.1f * Time.deltaTime` for at least be frame independent and remove the `WaitForSeconds`? This solution here results in a pretty strange stepwise fade ... I would actually rather use `Color.Lerp` ..

Comment: This is just an example, and is easier to understand. You can change the smoothness with this by reducing the wait for seconds...

Comment: Also this is taken from Unity official documentation. Color lerp is too much for only making a fade. Wait for seconds was meant for this, it is not frame dependent...

Comment: Then use `Mathf.Lerp` and use it only for the alpha value ;) either ways with lerp you are way more flexible. You can exactly control how long the transition should take and can add ease-in and ease-out to the fading etc. Also I don't know from which documentation you read that [`Color.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html) would be "too much" here

Comment: @derHugo it's another way to do it, but how would you use it in a coroutine? Also I think this is pretty easy to understand and customize.

Comment: it quite simple ;) `var currentColor = renderer.material.color; var targetColor = new Color(currentColor.r, currentColor.g, currentColor.b, 0); var timePassed = 0f; while (timePassed < duration) { var factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, passedTime / duration); /*already included easing*/ renderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, targetColor, factor); timePassed += Time.deltaTime; yield return null; } renderer.material.color = targetColor;`

Comment: Anyway ... This seems to not directly address the OP's issue